# ExtJS interval timer get data and insert new rows in grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have my `ExtJS 4.2` Application with a grid that initially will load and display data from a database table.

On server side, this table have new data about every 10 seconds, so I want to have a `Ext.TaskRunner` that every 10 senconds will go again to my `WebService`, get new data and insert it to the `grid`.

So, I dont want to get all data from server, just the new one. That's why I need to know how to do this with `ExtJS`. `TaskRunner` and `grid` (inserting new rows).

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: So what is the question here? How to only return new rows from the server? Or how to insert those new rows into the grid?

Comment: how to insert new rows into the grid (and if the scenario sounds reasonable). Thanks

Comment: See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load

Specifically the part about `addRecords`.

Comment: Ok I will read about it. Also I will have to read how to implement that using Ext.TaskRunner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how the function should be

```
Ext.TaskManager.start({
  run: function(){
    // Ajax request with store.add()
    // OR store.load({addRecords: true}) as @Evan Trimboli said
    // also you can add start parameter store.load({start: store.count()})
  },
  interval: 10000
});
```

Comment: How can I avoid the task to get executed when a process it's running?

Comment: You can either use `Ext.TaskManager.stop`, or don't use the *TaskRunner* and execute the function again on each success with `setTimeout`